# How to have two centered and clickable image link in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-dom, react-native-web

I want to have the two images clickable next to each over, this is my view:

```
    function MyView(props) {
        return (
              <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                <View style={{
                  // width: 230,
                  flex: 1,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                  <ExternalLink href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details">
                    <Image
                      source={availableAtGooglePlayImage}
                      style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 70,
                        flex: 1,
                        marginTop: 10,
                        resizeMode: 'contain',
                      }}
                    />
                  </ExternalLink>
                </View>
                <View style={{
                  // width: 230,
                  flex: 1,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                  <ExternalLink href="https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app">
                    <Image
                      resizeMode="stretch"
                      source={availableAtAppStoreImage}
                      style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 70,
                        flex: 1,
                        marginTop: 10,
                        resizeMode: 'contain',
                      }}
                    />
                  </ExternalLink>
                </View>
        );
    }
```

As soon as I use `flex: 1` on the parent view of `ExternalLink`, the image disappear.

I have not found a way to get those two images next to each over.

I have only find a way to have them on top of each over, and the whole width is clickable but I want only the image to be clickable.

How this is possible in react-native ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this code please, this is a working example [expo](https://snack.expo.io/BJ!RjSVW8) :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet ,Image,TouchableOpacity,Linking } from 'react-native';




export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <View>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>Linking.openURL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details")}>
        <Image style={{height:50,width:50}} source={{uri:"https://source.unsplash.com/random"}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
       <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>Linking.openURL("https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app")}>
        <Image style={{height:50,width:50}} source={{uri:"https://source.unsplash.com/random"}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    justifyContent:'space-around',
    alignItems:'center',

  },

});
```

Feel free for doubts

Comment: How can I have auto sizing on `width` or `height` ? (preserve aspect ratio)

Comment: Using this code, I am able to have proper clickable zone that respect the image appearance.  Is there a way using that jsx, to display 1 image per line when in portrait mode?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is {flexDirection: 'row'} property in style.
Copy code to https://snack.expo.io/

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, Linking } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>

          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.imageButton}
            onPress={() =>{Linking.openURL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details")}}
          >
            <Image
                resizeMode={'contain'}
                style={styles.coverImage}
                source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.imageButton}
          onPress={() =>{Linking.openURL("https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app")}}
          >
            <Image
                resizeMode={'contain'}
                style={styles.coverImage}
                source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    coverImage: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined
    },
    imageButton:{
      flex:1,
      height:70
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tested and this is not good. Use `resizeMode="stretch"` to see the whole clickable zone. `contain` will show the image correctly, but the link will be way over it.

Comment: I made the solution to provide clickable images side by side, you can set the image style as you like.